# Twitter rate limit information for POSTs

Tags: php, api, rest, twitter, rate-limiting

I am creating a Twitter webapp in PHP using TwitterOAuth and I soon went against the rate limit.

*stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 185 [message] => User is over daily status update limit. ) ) )*

what I am doing is (in API v1.1)

statuses/retweet/: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/retweet/%3Aid
statuses/update/: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update

So I read up about the rate limit:

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/application/rate_limit_status

What I don't find information about is how do I know where I am in terms of the POST rate limit. After reading https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limiting you would think they send you that information in the headers (X-Rate-Limit-Limit, ect). Here is an example header you get back when doing a post:

*Array ( [x_access_level] => read-write [x_connection_hash] => 5872d62634487fcda6d02ad7ba09f306 [x_content_type_options] => nosniff [x_frame_options] => SAMEORIGIN [x_response_time] => 246 [x_transaction] => a960a1986a130b96 [x_twitter_response_tags] => BouncerCompliant [x_xss_protection] => 1; mode=block )*

The information they said they would include, they just don't.

This page https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits does not make you any smarter either as it only lists GET rate limits.

Lastly I tried to follow this page https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/application/rate_limit_status to request information about my limits (and very important: where I am at at the moment in terms of remaining posts in the current time rate period). None of the response parts lets you know how many tweets to your own timeline you can still do. Here BTW, you DO get the limit information how often you may call this particular call:

*Array ( [x_access_level] => read-write [x_connection_hash] => 147c9e14fc999b5c02f6ce425a8f906b [x_content_type_options] => nosniff [x_frame_options] => SAMEORIGIN **[x_rate_limit_limit] => 180 [x_rate_limit_remaining] => 178 [x_rate_limit_reset] => 1440932964** [x_response_time] => 119 [x_transaction] => bfb31ca44b51d904 [x_twitter_response_tags] => BouncerCompliant [x_xss_protection] => 1; mode=block )*

But that only counts towards how often you can use /application/rate_limit_status. Additionally none of the listed limits in the response get decreased by a POST to their API.

It seems Twitter leaves us intentionally in the dark about this. Or what am I not getting?

Comment: Did you see this article: https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364 It lists a few limits for specific actions, the ones you are performing might be in there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I did, and it is useful information. But that page does not bring me further in the quest of where I am at in terms of remaining posts to be made in the current time slot and when it resets. That is ultimately the info I am looking for.

Comment: Ah. Well, if you are not getting any answers here, you should try Twitter's official developer hub. https://twittercommunity.com/ - don't forget to post an answer here if you find out. :-)